# Replace All Words In Document Body Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, replace

Firstly sorry for my english, i have code that doesnt work when I execute it on

```
<script language="javascript" src="/thecode.js"></script>
```

I put thecode.js on footer

```
var msg=document.body.innerHTML;
for(var i=0;i<msg.length;i++){
var tx=document.body[i].innerHTML;
tx=tx.replace(/dog/ig,'animal');
tx=tx.replace(/apple/ig,'fruit');
tx=tx.replace(/\[VIdEo\]/ig,'Video');
tx=tx.replace(/http\:\/\/example\.com/ig,'http://thelink.com');
document.body.innerHTML=tx;}
```

I think i dont make any fault, but when i execute it, its doesnt work.

thank for your attention... :)

Comment: there is no need of the for loop.... also `document.body[i]` is wrong... remove the for loop and `var tx=document.body.innerHTML;`

Comment: **Also never do this as it can remove any previous added event handlers** (added using script)

Comment: Note that processing HTML with a regular expression is [*doomed to fail*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) in weird and unexpected ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to iterate **body** element
try this:

want to change  to  with that js?
 i have used  to make it

```
function addTitleToSurveyUrls() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var el in elements) {
       var element = elements[el];
       var href = element.getAttribute("href");
       if(href.indexOf('survey_')>-1) {
           element.setAttribute('title', 'Some TITLE HERE');
       }
    }
}

function replaceBodyElements() {
    var tx=document.body.innerHTML;
        tx = tx.replace(/dog/ig,'animal');
        tx = tx.replace(/apple/ig,'fruit');
        tx = tx.replace(/\[VIdEo\]/ig,'Video');
        tx = tx.replace(/http\:\/\/example\.com/ig,'http://thelink.com');
    document.body.innerHTML=tx;
}

window.onload = function(){
    replaceBodyElements();
    addTitleToSurveyUrls();
    // ... some another operations
};
```

also

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var state = document.readyState; 
  if(state == 'complete') {
      replaceBodyElements();
      addTitleToSurveyUrls();
  }
}​
```

I've used **onload** event because maybe document has dynamic elements and etc. so better wait while all elements get loaded and change it.
or You can replace **window.onload** with **window.document.onload**

Comment: sorry for asking again, but i want to change
    <a href="survey_0.xhtml?ank=162780087&amp;odp=0">
to
    <a href="survey_0.xhtml?ank=162780087&amp;odp=0" title="survey">
with that js?<br>
i have used 
    <a href="survey_0.xhtml?$1">
to make it 
    <a href="survey_0.xhtml?$1" title="survey">
but it doesnt work for me :(

Comment: it doesnt work :( <br/>
I mean i want to add 'title="some title for SEO"' attribute to '<a>' element but i cant edit this '<a>' element.

Comment: SEO ? Add it when outputing html  from server-side. Most of robots does not handle dynamicaly changed elements by JS (:

Comment: it still doesnt work, i think i keep it like that, one link without title that no problem... And thankyou again, for your help so far... :)